# UWP C# Screen Recording Library

Tags: c#, encoding, uwp

I have been searching for a while but I cannot find any solid Windows library for recording the screen. I read about Windows Media Encoder but apparently it seems like being phased out or obsolete. I also encountered some Expression Encoder SDK, but it was discontinued.

I tried installing SharpAvi through Nuget shell but it failed.

Which library/SDK is the best for this purpose? My app shall be recording the desktop screen in any movie format (mp4, avi, etc).

Comment: I've not used UWP before, but many screen capture softwares/libraries these days use ffmpeg. If you have the time it could be feasible to build ffmpeg for UWP/WinRT (some sample codes  here -  (https://github.com/megayuchi/Windows-UWP ) and integrate it directly into your application. There are one or two libraries out there that work with an ffmpeg executable directly but this will probably cause headaches in UWP

Comment: @Asnivor I ll take  alook at it. I thought Windows has something built in for that purpose. UWP is closely related to WPF.